# How to connect asp.net web server to iPhone

Tags: iphone, asp.net, sql-server, xml

I realize that there are other posts asking similar questions, but do not quite answer the question I have. I apologize if this is not enough info, formatting is off, or whatnot. Its my first time posting.

Basically my group is doing an iPhone app that needs to interface with our sql server database. But because they can't talk directly with eachother we are implementing an asp.net medium that will accept XML and apparently will need to output JSOD. Currently I have a .asmx written with "working" code (test string inside code). Right now I am just trying to accept the XML from the iPhone. I feel like we are missing something either on his end (iPhone) or my end (.asmx). Hopefully you bright minds out there can fill me in because with our combined research....i feel theres something missing. Maybe im wrong and Ive we've got our stuff together which would be awesome.

apparently this is all he needs (according to his research) on his end in order to connect and transfer the information. obviously its not .asmx but it shouldn't matter the extension right?
`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myurl.com/RequestHandler.ashx"];`

Here is the code that I have with my .asmx (note the function is where the meat is at)

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Services;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

    namespace Outbreak_Mobile
    {
        [WebService(Namespace = "http://OutbreakMobile.net/")]
        [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
        [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
        // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
        // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
        public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
        {
            [WebMethod (Description="To intake an xml package from iPhone and store it")]
            public string iPhoneLocation(string xml)
            {
                //test string to output to screen
                string location = null;

                //test string of xml to be parsed
                //will be converting next line to parse input xml
                //string xml = @"<Player>
            //                  <Latitude>42.13245465</Latitude>
            //                  <Longitude>11.11111111</Longitude>
                //               </Player>";

                //line to parse document
                //xdocument doc = xdocument.parse(incoming xml)
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

                //grabs the information inside <player> tags
                XElement loc = doc.Elements("Player").SingleOrDefault();

                if (loc != null)
                {
                   var lat = (double)loc.Element("Latitude");
                   var lng = (double)loc.Element("Longitude");

                   location = "Lat: " + lat + '\n' + "Long: " + lng;
                }

                //this is what puts out to the screen
                return location;

            }
        }
    }
```

currently the output of the string 'location' was just for functionality testing and will change when I know that I am receiving the packages correctly. What are we missing in order to connect with one another?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a NSURL object. Now you need to create a NSURLConnection to download the data from that URL.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html

And to transfer the NSData object you got from the connection just use NSString -initWithData:encoding: method.

Comment: what about on the asp.net side? is that missing anything in order to take in the data from the iphone? Im guessing it has to consume it somehow before it goes into the function...Thank you for the quick reply btw :)

Comment: All I know about ASP is Response.Write(). Can't help you on that part, sorry :(

Comment: All good, thank you for the answer :) Hopefully other people would know the asp.net missing piece!